# How to fix 'Method Not Allowed' in Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to embed files from my OneDrive to a website using Graph API but I keep receiving status **405**.

I tried to get sharing link with Graph Explorer `/me/drive/items/CXXXXX907XXXAA!1XXX3/createLink?$type=embed` but i receive 405

> Method Not Allowed

error. I can see all files in my drive with API, but I can't share them. Graph Explorer has `Files.ReadWrite.All` permissions.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "notAllowed",
        "message": "Method Not Allowed",
        "innerError": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've changed the HTTP method in Graph Explorer to be `POST` and not `GET`.